# comparing arrays in php and in javascript return 2 different values. Why?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

Guys something is really bothering me.

In JavaScript - Arrays are objects, meaning each arrays is allocated with a piece of memory for that datatype.

So that makes sense when

```
arr1 = [1,2,3]
arr2 = [1,2,3]

arr1 == arr2 returns false
```

HOWEVER

In php that same scenario returns true.

Why is that the case.

Comment: the == and === are treating your variables as string , so by doing $ar1.toString() == $ar2.toString() you cna compare it in js. how ever it will not work if the order of element are not same.

Comment: you cna use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every to solve this problem when you are comparing two arrays in js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is why this returns false in **Javascript**:

When you create these 2 arrays:

```
arr1 = [1,2,3];
arr2 = [1,2,3];
```

you instantiate 2 different Array objects [see Array reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). So, even if they have the same elements, they are not the same object, so it returns false.

if you create only one object and copy the `reference` to another variable, like this:

```
var arr1 = [1,2,3];
var arr2 = arr1
(arr1 == arr2) //returns true
```

it will returns true because they have the reference to the same object([1,2,3]).

I think that you are familiar with O.O., if is not the case, please take a look at this: [Object Oriented Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming)

So, if you need to compare if each element of an array is equal to another in the same index you use the native function `every()` as @Prafulla Kumas Sahu mentioned. [every doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).

Here is a naive example of how you could compare if 2 arrays have the same elements using `every()`:

```
var arr1 = [1,2,3];
var arr2 = [1,2,3];

arr1.every(function(value, index){
    return value == arr2[index];
}); 
//returns true
```

In **PHP** there are extra `native` operators for Arrays in the PHP language, [php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php). They can check:

- $a + $b  Union   Union of $a and $b.
- $a == $b Equality    TRUE if $a and $b have the same key/value pairs.
- $a === $b    Identity    TRUE if $a and $b have the same key/value pairs in the same order and of the same types.
- $a != $b Inequality  TRUE if $a is not equal to $b.
- $a <> $b Inequality  TRUE if $a is not equal to $b.
- $a !== $b    Non-identity    TRUE if $a is not identical to $b.

So, it's **false** in **javascript** because the operator **==** check if the `instance` of an Array object has the same `reference` to another.

And it's **true** in **PHP** because there are `extra operators` for arrays, and the operator **==** check if two different arrays have the same pair value.

Comment: a very good explanation, thank you @tfidelis, but i think the OP understand that, but how about PHP ? is it the same case for PHP ? if yes, why PHP return true for the same scenario ?

Comment: Thanks great explanation. But the question is, why in PHP when comparing 2 object arrays the return is true? or is it in PHP they are not object arrays they are primitive values.. hmmm..

Comment: @JohnBryant you are right, i will edit the answer and tell you why is true in php.

Comment: So array in all languages is an object array? They are not primitive data types correct?

Comment: yes, every language implements in its own way. has its own methods to deal with, operators and so on. The idea of array is the same.

Comment: I feel like [Array Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php) deserves a link here.

Comment: Oops, visited links blend in well. I see it now, thanks